# Can't get ::after pseudo to appear below it's parent element using z-index

Tags: css

My goal is to position a CSS pseudo arrow below it's parent popup menu.

Setting z-index on the pseudo element to -1 works...that is, if I haven't set a z-index on the parent.

The issue is that it's a popup, it the parent must have a z-index set.

How can I set a z-index for the parent, and have the pseudo appear below?

```
.dropdown-menu {
    top: calc(100% + 5px);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    z-index: 9999;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.dropdown-menu::before {
    background-color: #706f6f;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) rotate(45deg);
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 11px 0px rgba(112, 111, 111, 0.3);
    margin-top: -5px;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: can you show us a code so we can see the issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif Added

Comment: and the html that goes with it please, so we can have something to test :)